DataColumn.Expression referencing another column
I am importing values from a file to a DataTable and one of the columns is a location column and unfortunately it contains both the latitude and longitude values, which requires me to split them.
Ideally, I would like to have two computed, Latitude and Longitude however I don't know how to write the expression for the DataColumn.Expression property.
private void CalcColumns()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable ();

    // Create the first column.
    DataColumn locationColumn = new DataColumn();
    locationColumn.ColumnName = "Location (Lat, Long)";
    locationColumn.DefaultValue = "40.00, -60.00";

    // Create the second, calculated, column.
    DataColumn latColumn = new DataColumn();
    latColumn.ColumnName = "Latitude";
    latColumn.Expression = ""; // what expression goes here

    // Create third column.
    DataColumn longColumn = new DataColumn();
    longColumn.ColumnName = "Longitude";
    longColumn.Expression = ""; // what expression goes here

    // Add columns to DataTable.
    table.Columns.Add(locationColumn);
    table.Columns.Add(latColumn);
    table.Columns.Add(longColumn);
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    DataView view = new DataView(table);
    dataGrid1.DataSource = view;
}

I tried Expression = "SUBSTRING(Location (Lat, Long),1,5)" but that gave me an error:
System.Data.EvaluateException: 'The expression contains undefined function call Location().'
So, tried Expression = "SUBSTRING('Location (Lat, Long)',1,5)" but that gave me Locat.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-8.0
An example from the Microsoft documentation shows:
private void CalcColumns()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable ();

    // Create the first column.
    DataColumn priceColumn = new DataColumn();
    priceColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    priceColumn.ColumnName = "price";
    priceColumn.DefaultValue = 50;

    // Create the second, calculated, column.
    DataColumn taxColumn = new DataColumn();
    taxColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    taxColumn.ColumnName = "tax";
    taxColumn.Expression = "price * 0.0862";

    // Create third column.
    DataColumn totalColumn = new DataColumn();
    totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    totalColumn.ColumnName = "total";
    totalColumn.Expression = "price + tax";

    // Add columns to DataTable.
    table.Columns.Add(priceColumn);
    table.Columns.Add(taxColumn);
    table.Columns.Add(totalColumn);

    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    DataView view = new DataView(table);
    dataGrid1.DataSource = view;
}

So, I should be able to refer to the column name as: Location (Lat, Long) but that threw the error.
How do I write the expression to get the value I'm after?

Why did you create columns with such name? Spaces and parenthesys in column names are usually a pain when dealing with any kind of sql expressions. Let the burden to display correct human text to the tool used to display infos, do not transfer this problem to your database that is not designed to do this.

I completely agree with you but it's not my data and I didn't generate the file. I'm working around issues caused by others. If it was up to me, I would have the lat/long values in separate columns also. Also, thankfully this is only for viewing the data and not persisting in a db.

I am sorry for you, being there. Do not wish this to happen to anyone.

It gets better, there's no trailing zeros in the lat values so no I have SUBSTRING working I'm picking up the comma and parts of the long value because there's no INDEXOF(",") type function. Back to the drawing board.

It's because of the parentheses, need an escape character. IRC `` or [] will work (may depend on .NET version), so you'd want:
"SUBSTRING([Location (Lat, Long)],1,5)" 

or
"SUBSTRING(`Location (Lat, Long)`,1,5)"

If you've got more references to that column though, may consider a more C# friendly name during the script (like LocationLatLong) then just fix at the final output.

@"SUBSTRING(Location (Lat, Long),1,5)" may also work? but, that just feels wrong.

Thank you! The two options in the answer worked in NET48.
p.s. The answer above in the comment didn't work (Cannot interpret token '@' at position 1.' error)
